# Php - get parent-script name

Tags: php, parent

parent.php:

```
require_once 'child.php';
```

child.php:

```
echo __FILE__;
```

It will show '.../child.php'

How can i get '.../parent.php'

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
print $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"];
```

Comment: This is not the correct answer. It is returning the file on which the request landed first.

Answer (score 21):

The chosen answer only works in environments that set server variables and specifically won’t work from a CLI script. Furthermore, it doesn't determine the parent, but only the topmost script file.

You can do almost the same thing from a CLI script by looking at $argv[0], but that doesn’t provide the full path.

The environment-independent solution uses **[debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php)**:

```
function get_topmost_script() {
  $backtrace = debug_backtrace(
      defined("DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS")
      ? DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS
      : FALSE);
  $top_frame = array_pop($backtrace);
  return $top_frame['file'];
}
```

Comment: Probably here must to be "array_shift" instead of "array_pop"

Comment: Nope, using `array_shift()` there will cause the function to return the name of the script file that contains `get_topmost_script()`, i.e. `__FILE__`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that : the `__FILE__` magic constant indicates in which file it is written ; and that is all.

If you want to know which PHP script was initially called (which URL was requested, for instance), you might have more luck looking at the `$_SERVER` superglobal : it contains many informations, including some that will help you *(like `SCRIPT_FILENAME` or `SCRIPT_NAME`, for instance)* ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**Straight to the solution:**

Parent Script:

```
echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
```

Child Script (included file in parent script):

```
echo __FILE__;
```

**Make a file called "parent.php" with contents:**

```
include('child.php');
```

**Make a file called "child.php" with contents:**

```
echo "My Parent is at: " . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] . "<br>";
echo "I'm at: " .  __FILE__;
```

You get the idea...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"])` or, if you like the script nam only, you can use `basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], '.php')`.

Answer (score 0):

The other way to do this (works under both Apache and CLI) is by using the `get_included_files()` function. It returns an array with all of the included files (including the initial calling script) in the order they were run.

`get_included_files()[0]` = full path of initial script.

E.g

/myscripts/Parent.php

```
<?php
   echo("Called from parent: ".get_included_files()[0]."\r\n");
   include("/otherscripts/Child.php");
   echo("Called again from parent: ".get_included_files()[0]."\r\n");
?>
```

/otherscripts/Child.php

```
<?php
   echo("Called from child: ".get_included_files()[0]."\r\n");
?>
```

Output:

```
> php /myscripts/Parent.php
Called from parent: /myscripts/Parent.php
Called from Child: /myscripts/Parent.php
Called again from parent: /myscripts/Parent.php
```

I eventually found the solution to this elsewhere on stackoverflow ([Get absolute path of initially run script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645082/get-absolute-path-of-initially-run-script)) while looking for something else so have modified and added to this question as this was where I landed first!

Answer (score 0):

If you have layers of "include" files and want to get where the request came from, I found the easiest way is to have the requesting parent pass it's ID through:

parent script:

```
required_once('child.php');
childFunction(__FILE__);
```

child script:

```
function childFunction($source);
    echo 'Hi '.$source.', how can I help you?';
}
```

To make it more useful for debugging, best replace `__FILE__` with a string which includes the line number,  such as "parent.php L1234".