# PHP How to get Full Path to the file included home and user

Tags: php, path

How can I get in PHP the full path to the file?

For example:

```
 /home/yob/public_html/demo/envato/cce/tug/cron/cron.php
```

I want the folder where the file is:

```
 /home/yob/public_html/demo/envato/cce/tug/cron/
```

Comment: You know there's a search bar at the top of the site - This question has been answered plenty.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get absolute path of current script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645082/get-absolute-path-of-current-script)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP < 5.3

```
$fullpath = dirname(__FILE__);
```

PHP >= 5.3

```
$fullpath = __DIR__;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: No I did not explain good. I need to know the path of the website, of the folder where the file is, not the path of the file itself. I need the full path to the folder where this file is