# PHP Absolute & Relative Paths

Tags: php, function, path

I have this directory structure:

```
/style/style.php
/style/graphics/logo.png
/cp-admin/index.php
```

style.php contains the following function, which echoes the logo:

```
function logo(){
    echo "<p><img class = 'logo' src = 'style/graphics/logo.png'></p>";
}
```

I am using this function so that if I change the path of the logo, or need to include something else along with it, all it takes is to modify the function, and changes are reflected in all pages.

However, when I am including from /cp-admin/index.php, the path above is taken relatively to index.php, instead of the original function's path.

I want the function to have a path which is referenced-to from the function itself, rather than from all the pages where it's included.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Using functions and functional programming are completely separate topics indeed.

Comment: You're right, my mistake. Was going for 'function' and I pressed the wrong one. Thanks for the heads-up - fixed :)

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of: pass the current directory in to logo() as an argument, which then checks [`__FILE__`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645082/get-absolute-path-of-current-script) and constructs the correct relative path between the two directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to navigate in your folder, you can use

`/` which is the root and after make your path since this place (asbolute)

or use your a relative path, in this case, you go back until the common folder with '..'

Try in absolute

```
echo "<p><img class = 'logo' src = '/style/graphics/logo.png'></p>";

                                    ^ from the root
```

or relative

```
echo "<p><img class = 'logo' src = 'graphics/logo.png'></p>";

                                    ^ style.php and the folder graphics are in the same parent folder 'style'
```

Comment: What gives? All that was missing was that small '/' :) That did the trick - thanks a lot!