# include_once error : failed to open stream in Boonex Dolphin v7.0.9

Tags: php, include, boonex-dolphin

First let me say I'm a beginner in PHP, specifically PHP Object-oriented programming.

I'm working on a V7.0.9 dolphin version.http://www.boonex.com/dolphin

While I'm trying to include a class.php from a 3rd-part developer I work with

```
<?php
include_once ('modules/developer/configure/classes/class.php');
```

I get this error :

```
Warning: include_once(modules/developer/configure/classes/ClassExample.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/dolphin/inc/classes/BxDolPageView.php(612) : eval()'d code on line 2
Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'modules/developer/configure/classes/ClassExample.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:') in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/dolphin/inc/classes/BxDolPageView.php(612) : eval()'d code on line 2
Fatal error: Class 'ClassExample' not found in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/dolphin/inc/classes/BxDolPageView.php(612) : eval()'d code on line 6
```

I'm trying to figure out where is the problem... does it comes from Boonex? or is it linked to my server configuration? I really don't know where to begin to resolve...

Thx in advance for your kind help if you get knowledge on it

[EDIT] I omit to say that I'm writing my code inside PHP block, on the news homepage. Initial HTML blocks have been customised in order to accept PHP.

Comment: you should include your files as this: `include_once(__DIR__ . "path/to/root/of/your/site/modules/developer/configure/classes/class.php");` \_\_DIR\_\_ is the folder path of the php file where you write \_\_DIR\_\_.

Comment: I tried and failed : Boonex leave the __DIR__information of my code! (I omit to say that I'm writing my php code in block, on the news homepage)

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant forgot a "/" : `include_once(__DIR__ . "/path/from/root/of/your/site/modules/developer/configure/classes/class.php");`

Comment: Same issue: dolphin not allow me to use the __DIR__ constant

Comment: I'm pretty sure you screwed things up with your customization of the HTML blocks to accept PHP. The error messages mentions "eval()'d code". I guess you added support for PHP by using the `eval()` function. Check there first...

Comment: Actually the eval() function is internal to dolphin... it refers to the BxDolPageView.php, which is very very official.

Comment: are you sure you need to use "include_once" ? Maybe dolphin provide a custom function to load this class. I think you could find more help in their forum

Comment: I'm looking on this way

Answer (score 0):

You should insert the full path of the file you want to include. You can use `__DIR__` (or `dirname(__FILE__)` to get the current directory, then, your code should look like this:

```
<?php
// add this to see an error if file is not found
// and don't forget to remove this in production mode
error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$path = dirname(__FILE__).'/';
include_once ($path.'modules/developer/configure/classes/class.php');
```

Usually, the first called file define a constant like `define('ROOT_DIR', __DIR__.'/')` and use it for every inclusion or require.

**EDIT** : if `__FILE__` and `__DIR__` are not available because of server configuration, you can looks at [Get absolute path of current script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645082/get-absolute-path-of-current-script) ( and specially [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17471242/724027) ) for alternatives

Comment: Thank you for the error_reporting trick, I didn't know that and it shows many (minor) errors I have to correct. But it does not solve my initial issue, as dolphin don't let met write neither __FILE__ nor __DIR__ in my code (inside the block). It automatically erases both terms...

Comment: So try the link I added in my answer for alternatives, or check the dophin documentation about how to include file.