# php copy() using destination absolute path

Tags: php

I cannot google anywhere that one cannot use absolute path in copy() destination. However,

```
$baseUrl_master_MM = "http://mysite.öä/MM/";
$img_dir = 'img_1';
$img = '01.jpg';

$orig_online = $baseUrl_master_MM.$img_dir.'/'.$img;
$dest_online = '../../mm_img/'.$img_dir.'-online.jpg';
$copy = copy($orig_preview, $dest_preview);
```

works fine, but the same with absolute path

```
$baseUrl_master_MM = "http://mysite.öä/MM/";
$baseUrl_master_MM_online = "http://mysite.öä/mm_img/";
$img_dir = 'img_1';
$img = '01.jpg';

$orig_online = $baseUrl_master_MM.$img_dir.'/'.$img;
$dest_online = $baseUrl_master_MM_online.$img_dir.'-online.jpg';
$copy = copy($orig_preview, $dest_preview);
```

will give no errors and copies no files.

Destination directory exists, and rights are 777. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you're missing something. When the source is an URL, PHP is smart enough to download it for you (it actually uses HTTP for this - it has no idea that it's your website/the current website) and then when you try to use it in the destination, it obviously gives up as it can't just upload to a website. Just use an absolute *server* path (`eg. /home/user/www/mm_img/` or `C:\wamp\www\mm_img\ `). `dirname(__FILE__)` will give you the directory of the current file. An absolute path is not the same as an absolute URL.

Comment: What you're using is not the server's absolute path, it's the public web address.If you really want the absolute path see this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645082/get-absolute-path-of-current-script

Comment: I'd mark H2o*n's comment as correct answer, if it wasn't a comment..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the HTTP protocol to copy a file on a server. Taken from the PHP documentation on [HTTP wrapper](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php)

> Allows read-only access to files/resources via HTTP 1.0, using the HTTP GET method.

To copy to your local server, use an absolute path.

Comment: You might want to explain to OP what an "absolute path" is, as OP said "*works fine, but the same with absolute path*".

Answer (score 1):

Please do the following :

```
   if(!@copy($orig_preview, $dest_preview))
    {
        $errors= error_get_last();
        echo "COPY ERROR: ".$errors['type'];
        echo "<br />\n".$errors['message'];
    } else {
        echo "File copied from remote!";
    }
```

Tell what the error's you see?

Also absolute path should look like :

```
   $abs =  $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

**Sorry for post as answer , couldn't post as comment**

Comment: Yes, it gives:
COPY ERROR: 2
copy(httu://www.mysite.öä/mm_img/MM-1167-preview.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections.

After getting less ignorant on absolute and public paths, it gives
File copied from remote!

Thank you all!