# In PHP how to save directory the php file is in to a variable (centos)

Tags: php, active-directory

so say my php file "example.php" is in the directory "/user/example"

I thought that the line `"$dir = getcwd();"` would save `"/user/example"` to `$dir` but instead it is saving the directory that the user running the script is in, e.g. if I run the script from the root directory, the `$dir` variable will contain the root directory.

Is there a command I can use or a tip you can give me so that I can save the directory that the php file is in?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645082/get-absolute-path-of-current-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to combine your existing code using dirname() with a call to basename():

```
$parent = basename(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the path to the current file using the magic constant

```
__FILE__
```

And the directory it resides in using:

```
__DIR__
```

Sample demo usage:

```
 <?php
 $dir = __DIR__; // /usr/example
 $filename = __FILE__; // /usr/example/example.php
 $basename = basename(__FILE__); // example.php
```

Be warned that this is not the file that is executed, but the current script, so if you make an include, or call a method/function from another file these magic constants will change(they're named "constants" solely because you cannot change them yourself).