# php get relative path till project name

Tags: php

I am new to php. I am trying to get relative path of my project, but not exactly as required.

I mean I have a directory structure like : `'/opt/www/abc/myproj/folder1/folder2/myfile.php'`

So in myfile.php I am trying to get path till my project ie., `/opt/www/abc/myproj`

I have tried differnt ways like using `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`, `dirname(__FILE__)`, `basename(__FILE__)` etc..  but still no luck.

Could anyone please tell me how can I achieve above.

Comment: What was the ouput of `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Its showing till '/opt/www/abc/'

Comment: This answer may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4645101/77643

Comment: Unfortunately none of them are working :(

Answer (score 2):

Does `dirname(__FILE__)` not return anything? It should give you the location of the script from where you are running. You can then traverse up the path using

```
. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..'
```

for each level upwards so for one level above would be:

```
dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..'
```

Wrap a `realpath()` function around it to tidy things up... So for your particular scenario:

```
realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access the file using,

```
$path=$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/myproj/folder1/folder2/myfile.php';
```

Comment: iam getting output as: /opt/www/abc/   , but I need as : /opt/www/abc/myproj