# Execute PHP file located in another folder

Tags: php

I have a script that uploads a file. It then creates a new folder and moves the uploaded file to that folder along with the another script.

After the file is moved, I need to run a second script that resides in the new folder. But I need the second script to use its path and NOT the path of where it is called/executed from. (the upload script)

This is how I have tried to execute the script from the upload script.

`exec("php-cli  uploads/".$dirname."/".$file_name."/generate_thumbs.php");`

I have error reporting on but nothing is generated. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you thought about using a cURL to achieve what you need done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory), use [`chdir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) before `exec()`.
You can pass either absolute or relative directory name.
To execute PHP from PHP you can use [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) instead of `exec()`.

edit your upload script to:

```
<?php
    // ... upload the file ...

    // ,,open'' the target directory
    chdir("uploads/$dirname/$file_name/");

    // start the thumbs script
    // this filename is relative to "uploads/$dirname/$file_name/"
    include "generate_thumbs.php";
?>
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is within your second script to use path to where the script is.

As found in the answer:
[Get absolute path of current script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645082/get-absolute-path-of-current-script)

From there you can write your script to operate from where it is as long as you can resolve where it is.

Comment: Thanks. lukasrozs answer fixed my issue.