# How to get the exact directory of a script

Tags: php

Say I run

http://mymaindomain.com/helloworld/somescript.php

I want `http://mymaindomain.com/helloworld/`

How do I do so?

Comment: Not the directory inside the machine but the directory that face the public. So not /root/htdocs/public_html/helloworld/ more like http://domainname.com/helloworld/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get absolute path of current script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645082/get-absolute-path-of-current-script)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 1):

Would you please check my answer?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41407858/3821823

You can also define const variable like this:

```
const BASE_URL = 'http://mymaindomain.com/helloworld/';
// or
define('BASE_URL', 'http://mymaindomain.com/helloworld/');

echo BASE_URL;
```