# HTML - Access data from remote online CSV files

Tags: javascript, python, html, csv, remote-access

I've been trying to implement some HTML code that accesses weather data in historical CSV files online, and perform maths on the data once I selectively extract it.

In the past, I've programmed in Python and had no problems doing this by using `pycurl.Curl()`.  HTML is a complete nightmare in comparison:  **`XMLHttpRequest()`** does technically work, but web browsers automatically block access to all foreign URLs *(because of the Same-Origin Policy)*.  Not good.

Any ideas and alternative approaches would be very helpful!

Comment: The same origin policy exists for a reason - I can assure you that, although it's a pain, it's in fact quite good when you consider the shenanigans it prevents.

Comment: True. I might go back to investigating how to upload files into the same location as the HTML code.  Easier said than done when you're using GoDaddy, with their lack of documentation.

Comment: GoDaddy supports php, right? Maybe have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645082/get-absolute-path-of-current-script to work out where you need to dump said files. Not sure if you get write access from scripts though...

Answer (score 0):

I would look into YQL for this.

https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/

Nice Gist as example querying a CSV file.
https://gist.github.com/RandomEtc/491827

Best of luck!

Comment: I'll give it a go, looks like it might be what I need.

Comment: Looks like it might've worked at some stage, but from what I gather, YQL has been discontinued as of mid-2017.  And it makes sense because the YQL examples on their main website don't seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pushing against the boundaries set forth in your question.. if you're simply wanting to do it in JavaScript, but outside the context of a browser, have you considered working in Node?

Comment: I'd like to work outside of browsers, but my goal is to put this tool on a website for user access, so unfortunately I'm stuck with HTML.  But I didn't realise it would be so hard to simply access remote data files....

Comment: You could do your cURL work on the server, and have the HTML access it from your server, in a same-origin manner