# PHP reliably determine path of caller file

Tags: php, security, path, filesystems

I have a file which will be included in a parent, so-to-speak, file. I need to reliably determine the path of the parent file from within the child file.

My first thought was `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` but that can be easily manipulated from the parent file.

Next thing I thought of was `getcwd()` but that will not always work, apache always provides the directory of the executed script but if it is run from cli or cron that is not the case.

If I can not trust the parent file, what is a secure way of determining its location from inside the file that is to be included?

Comment: Use the Constant `__FILE__` bind this value to an $variable in the parent and then you have it in the include.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I can't trust the parent file, `$variable` can be anything.

Comment: If you do it like this `<?php $parent=__FILE__; include 'child.php'` you can ;)

Comment: *"If I can not trust the parent file"* - if you cannot trust the file, how can you be sure it will include your script without modifications? This seems pointless to me.

Comment: As side note, in modern oop code, mostly `include` is only used for `autoloading`.

Comment: Take a look at the answer with the most upvotes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318608/php-get-parent-script-name

Answer (score 2):

Offhand, can't find anything that'll directly give you the "parent" path in an include chain, but you CAN use `debug_backtrace()`:

./z.php

```
<?php
include('y/y.php');
```

./y/y.php

```
<?php
var_dump(debug_backtrace());
```

And then:

```
$ php z.php
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["file"]=>
    string(44) "/home/marc/z/z.php"
    ["line"]=>
    int(3)
    ["function"]=>
    string(7) "include"
  }
```

}